Mikrotik: strange behavior with multi WAN routing

router is connected to global network via one phisical port.
ovpn connection is established by mikrotik

I need to route some destination addresses address-list=vpn_list via ovpn. This list is containging global IP addresses.
Created additional table:
[admin@Microtik] > /routing/table print detail
Flags: D - dynamic; X - disabled, I - invalid; U - used 
 0 D   name="main" fib 

 1     name="vpn" fib 

Added mangle rule:
[admin@Microtik] > /ip/firewall/mangle print  
Flags: X - disabled, I - invalid; D - dynamic 
 0  D ;;; special dummy rule to show fasttrack counters
      chain=prerouting action=passthrough 

 1  D ;;; special dummy rule to show fasttrack counters
      chain=forward action=passthrough 

 2  D ;;; special dummy rule to show fasttrack counters
      chain=postrouting action=passthrough 

 3    chain=prerouting action=mark-routing new-routing-mark=vpn passthrough=no dst-address-list=vpn_list in-interface-list=LAN log=no log-prefix="" 

dstnat:
[admin@Microtik] > /ip/firewall/nat print
Flags: X - disabled, I - invalid; D - dynamic 
 0    ;;; defconf: masquerade
      chain=srcnat action=masquerade out-interface-list=WAN ipsec-policy=out,none 

 1    chain=srcnat action=masquerade out-interface=ovpn log=no log-prefix="" 

And added route (some routes connects different LANs (using another l2tp tunnel):
[admin@Microtik] > /ip/route print detail
Flags: D - dynamic; X - disabled, I - inactive, A - active; 
c - connect, s - static, r - rip, b - bgp, o - ospf, i - is-is, d - dhcp, v - vpn, m - modem, y - bgp-mpls-vpn; H - hw-offloaded; + - ecmp 
 0  Xs   ;;; Old router network
         dst-address=192.168.1.0/24 gateway=bridge 

 1  As   dst-address=0.0.0.0/0 routing-table=main gateway=192.168.1.1 immediate-gw=192.168.1.1%ether1 distance=1 scope=30 target-scope=10 suppress-hw-offload=no 

   DAc   dst-address=10.0.0.0/24 routing-table=main gateway=bridge immediate-gw=bridge distance=0 scope=10 suppress-hw-offload=no local-address=10.0.0.1%bridge 

 2  As   ;;; bliz cross network route
         dst-address=10.0.1.0/24 routing-table=main pref-src=10.0.0.1 gateway=172.16.0.2 immediate-gw=172.16.0.2%l2tp-bliz distance=1 scope=30 target-scope=10 
         suppress-hw-offload=no 

   DAc   dst-address=172.16.0.2/32 routing-table=main gateway=l2tp-bliz immediate-gw=l2tp-bliz distance=0 scope=10 suppress-hw-offload=no 
         local-address=172.16.0.1%l2tp-bliz 

 3  Is   dst-address=192.168.0.0/24 routing-table=main pref-src=10.0.0.1 gateway=l2tp-bliz immediate-gw=l2tp-bliz check-gateway=ping distance=1 scope=30 target-scope=10 
         suppress-hw-offload=no 

   DAc   dst-address=192.168.1.0/24 routing-table=main gateway=ether1 immediate-gw=ether1 distance=0 scope=10 suppress-hw-offload=no local-address=192.168.1.254%ether1 

   DAc   dst-address=192.168.219.0/24 routing-table=main gateway=ovpn immediate-gw=ovpn distance=0 scope=10 suppress-hw-offload=no local-address=192.168.219.4%ovpn 

 4  As   dst-address=0.0.0.0/0 routing-table=vpn gateway=ovpn immediate-gw=ovpn distance=1 scope=30 target-scope=10 suppress-hw-offload=no 

PS: 192.168.1.1 - default gateway for WAN. 10.0.0.0/24 - my LAN.
All right?
The problem that resources from address-list=vpn_list works extremely slow with freezes (works via desired ovpn interface`).
When I go to tools and click start on Torch page everything is getting to fine. After stop - the problem comes back.

Where is my mistake?

Note: I do not think Microtik uses Linux, at least the network stack is different (and so no iproute), so the question may be off-topic here.

@GiacomoCatenazzi mikrotik is based on linux

Disabling fasttrack rule in fw filter helps for me.
